# G++/LD fails: can't find library when library isn't actually needed

Tags: gcc, linker, makefile

I have a program `foo` I'm trying to compile and link and I'm running into a chicken and egg dillemma.

For reasons I'll explain below, Within a given directory I'm forced to add a link to several libraries we build (let's call them `libA` and `libB`) regardless of my target. I know I only actually need `libA` for my program; so after all libs are built and this binary is built I verified with `ldd -u -r foo` to show  that `libB` is an unused direct dependency.

Being unused I altered the makefiles and flags such that `libB` is enveloped with `-Wl --as-needed` and `-Wl --no-as-needed`. I make rebuild, use `ldd` again and this time it doesn't show any unused deps. So far so good.

Now the fun part: Since its unused I would expect that if `libB` is not found/available/built that I should still be able to compile and link `foo` as long is `libA` is available.  (example: If I did a fresh checkout and only built `libA` before trying to compile this specific test).  But `ld` errors out with `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lB`

This suggests that `ld` needs to locate `libB` even if it won't need any of the symbols it provides?  That doesn't seem to make sense. If all symbolic dependencies are already met, why does it even need to look at this other library? (That would explain the problem ld has and why this is not possible)

Is there a way I can say "Hey don't complain if you can't find this library and we shouldn't need to link with it?"

**The promised reasons below**
For various reasons beyond my control I have to share makeflags with many other tests in this directory due to the projects makefile hierarchy.  There is a two level makefile for all these tests that says `foo` is a phony target, his recipe is `make -f generictest.mk target=foo`, and the `generictest.mk` just says that the source file is `$(target).C`, that this binary needs to use each library we build, specifies relative path to our root directory and then includes root's generic makefile.  The root directory generic makefile expands all the other stuff out (flags, options, compiler, auto-gen of dependencies through g++ etc), and most importantly for each statement that said "use libX" in `generictest.mk` it adds `-lX` to the flags (or in my case enveloped in as-needed's)

While I'm well aware there are lots of things that are very unideal and/or horribly incorrect in terms of makefile best practices with this, I don't have the authority/physical ability to change it.  And compared to the alternative employed in other folders, where others make individual concrete copies of this makefile for each target, I greatly prefer it; because that forces me to edit all of them whenever want to revise our whole make pattern, and yields lot of other typos and problems.

I could certainly create another `generictest.mk` like file to use for some tests and group together those using each based on actual library needs, but it would be kind of neat if I didn't have to as long as I said "you don't all of them, you need each of them but only if you actually use it".

Comment: The makefile is misdesigned — or designed on now outdated assumptions.  Redesign it so that you don't try to link with libraries that neither exist nor are necessary to the test program in question.  The other option is to make sure `libB` is built — it becomes an explicit dependency of the targets in the `makefile` (the `generictest.mk`).  It should be, anyway, of course; if the programs are linked with it, the programs (or the link command lines) depend on the libraries existing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm aware its severely misdesigned.  I just don't have the ability to change it.  Again I agree with everything you said; but it doesn't help me.  I can make it depend on libB but I don't want to waste the time of building libB when I don't need it. They only don't exist because I haven't built them; in a 'real' build, they are normally all going to exist.

Comment: OK;  if you won't listen to words of wisdom, you'll have to go on festering in the morass of broken builds.  Or wait for some genius to come up with a solution.  But your best bet is not to fight the system imposed by the compiler and linker; your best bet is to fix the brokenness in the tools that are abusing the compiler and linker (meaning the `generictest.mk` file).  Your call...have fun!  ("I can't fix" doesn't cut it in software; software is malleable — that's why it is called _soft_.  If it is the powers-that-be that are imposing the rules, ask them how to work around your dilemma.)

Comment: ? I'm not disagreeing with you. I'm trying to find a workaround to fit the conundrum I'm in. I am not able to change the whole system from the ground up; it is not within my authority. Were it up to me I would be doing exactly as you specified and wouldn't have had to ask this absurd question.

Comment: Software is only as malleable as your managers and legacy compatibilty agreements allow it to be.  And just because it can be changed doesn't mean its worth the time to them; in the real world, you'll often find people are skeptical of the 'risk' of such a change for such a minimal benefit, even if you and I know its an apocalypse waiting to happen :-p cheers though i think you reaffirmed my use of another file at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way that the linker can know that the library is not needed.  Even after all your "normal" libraries are linked there are still lots and lots of unresolved symbols: symbols for the C runtime library (`printf`, etc.).  The linker has no idea where those are going to come from.

Personally I'd be surprised if the linker *didn't* complain, even if every single symbol was already resolved.  After all there may be fancy things at work here: weak bindings, etc. which may mean that symbols found later on the link line would be preferred over symbols found earlier (I'm not 100% sure this is possible but I wouldn't be surprised).

As for your situation, if you know that the library is not needed can't you just use `$(filter-out ...)` on the link command line to get rid of it?  You'd have to write your own explicit rule for this with your own recipe, rather than using a default one, but at least you could use all the same variables.

Alternatively it MIGHT be possible to play some tricks with target-specific variables.  Declare a target-specific variable for that target that resets the variable containing the "bad library" with a value that doesn't contain it (maybe by using `$(filter-out ...)` as above), and it will override that value for that target only.  There are some subtle gotchas with target-specific variables overriding "more general" variables but I think it would work.

Comment: Thanks, I'm utilizing your first point, it becomes a halting problem of sorts.